# Cucumber feature file does not identify the steps

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, cucumber, gherkin

I have written my firsy cucumber feature file. When I run the feature file as Cucumber Feature, I get below errors

1. "WARNING: Cucumber-JVM's --format option is deprecated. Please use --plugin instead." - I used "plugin" in my @CucumberOptions of runner class, but still getting the same error

2.It says I do not have any scenario and steps
Feature: Validate Modular GUI pages

Scenario: Validate Login Page # C:/Selenium/RegressionTest/ModularRegression/src/GUI/features/Validate.feature:3
    Given: Modular GUI is opened
    When: Validate the login page
    Then: Login to the Modular

0 Scenarios
0 Steps

3. I'm not getting snippets for my steps.

I have added following jars to the library
[Jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7nc9.jpg)

This is my runner class,
package GUI;

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        format = {"pretty", "json:target/"},
        features = {"src/GUI/"}
        )
public class GUIRunner {

}
```

This is my feature file,

```
Feature: Validate Modular GUI pages

  Scenario: Validate Login Page
    Given: Modular GUI is opened
    When: Validate the login page
    Then: Login to the Modular
```

I would really appreciate if someone can point out what is missing in my code.

Thank you very much

[EDITED]
This is the actual error:

> WARNING: Cucumber-JVM's --format option is deprecated. Please use
>   --plugin instead. Feature: Validate Modular GUI pages
>
> Scenario: Validate Login Page #
>   C:/Selenium/RegressionTest/ModularRegression/src/GUI/features/Validate.feature:3
>       Given: Modular GUI is opened
>       When: Validate the login page
>       Then: Login to the Modular
>
> 0 Scenarios 0 Steps 0m0.000s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had an extra ":" in my feature file after Given, When and Then.

It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing your feature files in your class path.

You don’t tell us how you are running Cucumber. But if you would run it as a part of a Maven build, which is among the easier options, you would like to store your feature file in

./src/test/resources/GUI

An easy way to get started is to download the getting started project from GitHub, https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

It will give you a a working project that you can modify to contain your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Sundberg

I do not use Maven, I jsut build that using empty project. followed instaruction at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pD4B839qfos

I haven't got a feedback from the youtube poster

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Currently I have my feature files at src\GUI\features,

I also tried with location you mentioned. I'm still geting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Where are your step definitions located? Try adding the tag 'glue' like below

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        format = {"pretty", "json:target/"},
        features = {"src/GUI/"},
        glue = {"path/to/steps"} 
        )
public class GUIRunner {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the existing answers: remember to write "Scenario: " before writing actual code of the step. That might seem absolutely trivial, but without it you'll always be getting "0 features, 0 steps" message.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuTKWwD37Tg

Answer (score 0):

Please add `tags = {"@SmokeTest"}` or `tags = {"@RegresionTest"}`

Answer (score 0):

please add  `tags= {"@SmokeTest","@RegressionTest"}` in `@CucumberOptions()`

Answer (score 0):

Replace **format** with **plugin** as format option was deprecated from **v1.2.0 onwards on 30-October-2014**. Example below -

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:features/functional/",
                     glue = {"com.jacksparrow.automation.steps_definitions.functional" },
                   plugin = { "pretty","json:target/cucumber-json/cucumber.json",
                            "junit:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.xml", "html:target/cucumber-reports"},
                   tags = { "@BAMS_Submitted_State_Guest_User" },
                   strict = false,
                   dryRun = false,
               monochrome = true)
```